# Managed modules and platform independence

Tags: .net

The .Net model is something like this :
C# Code -> C# Compiler -> Managed Module (Win PE) -> CLR -> "Hello, world"
The code is compiled to a managed module which invokes CLR which in turn does the necessary work to run the code (assuming it's an exe).

My initial understanding was that .Net is the Microsoft equivalent of Java Framework with CLR the MS equivalent of JVM. But the interesting hitch here is that the Managed module is a Win PE which means that any OS that wants to use .Net must accept and use the Win PE format too. My questions are:

1. Is the theory so far correct?
2. What are the chances of Linux/Unix/Solaris/OSX etc. supporting/implementing the Win PE format?
3. Are there any alternatives that are currently being worked on to make the interoperability happen?
4. What route does Java take to make it executable on different platforms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page).

To answer your questions:

1. Yes.
2. They already do, through Wine and Mono.
3. I'm not sure what you mean.
4. Java compiles to `.jar` files which are opened by the Java runtime in the same way that a `.doc` file is opened by Microsoft Word.

Comment: Ok. So, if they can come up with a CLR for Linux etc. the .Net code will run seamlessly on it?

Comment: There already is a CLR for Linux - Mono.  However, not all code will run seamlessly.